# PHP foreach stuck at values in first key

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a multidimensionel array of different departments, and a want to loop through it using a foreach loop, but for some reason, the foreach loop grabs the values under the first key through every iteration.

The array looks like this:

```
$departmentArray = 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dpt_id] => 5
            [dpt_name] => Administration
            [dpt_employees] => Array
                (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [started] => 2000-06-01
                        [stopped] => 9999-99-99
                        [empl_id] => 21
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [started] => 2000-06-01
                        [stopped] => 2010-01-01
                        [empl_id] => 23
                    )
            )
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dpt_id] => 6
            [dpt_name] => Warehouse
            [dpt_employees] => Array
                (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [started] => 2000-10-01
                        [stopped] => 2012-01-01
                        [empl_id] => 30
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [started] => 2007-10-17
                        [stopped] => 9999-99-99
                        [empl_id] => 197
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

And the foreach loop looks like this:

```
foreach($departmentArray as $key => $value) {

    print_r($key);
    print_r($value['dpt_name']);

}
```

And this prints:

```
0 Administration 1 Administration.
```

Does anyone know, why the loop does not move forward in the array and grab the value (Warehouse) under key/index 1 during its second iteration?

Comment: No, *this* code would not print that. If your own code prints it, you are doing something different. Possibly iterating by reference and changing the values?

Comment: Thank you for answering. You are right, I am iterating by reference earlier in the code, where I use the same name, I will look into it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total stab into the dark:

You have used `$value` in a `foreach` loop before as reference, like so:

```
foreach ($foo as &$value) { ... }

foreach ($departmentArray as $key => $value) { ... }
```

This is a well known side-effect of references. `unset($value)` after the first loop.

Comment: Thank you for your stab in the dark, I think you are right, as I am iterating by reference earlier i the code. Should i unset() the $value in the first loop inside the curly brackets?